# How to listen on multiple ports with warp?

Tags: rust, warp

```
warp::serve(routes)
    .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030))
    .await;
```

How can I listen to different ports for http requests and websocket connection?

Comment: See [Review: how to listen on both ipv4 and ipv6? · Issue #628 · seanmonstar/warp](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/issues/628)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start two separate instances and run them concurrently:

```
tokio::join!(
    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)),
    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3031)),
);
```

Inspired by [Run multiple actix app on different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59642576/2189130)

Answer (score 6):

Generally, there is no reason to use a separate port for WebSockets.

However, if you really want to listen on multiple ports (this has other use cases such as supporting plaintext and TLS off one `Server` instance), you can use `Server::run_incoming`. For this, you need to create your own listeners and combine their `TcpListenerStream`s using stream combinators.

```
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio_stream::{StreamExt, wrappers::TcpListenerStream};

let listener1 = TcpListener::bind((Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST, 3030)).await?;
let listener2 = TcpListener::bind((Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST, 3031)).await?;

let stream1 = TcpListenerStream::new(listener1);
let stream2 = TcpListenerStream::new(listener2);

let combined = stream1.merge(stream2);

warp::serve(routes).run_incoming(combined).await?;
```

I admit that have not tried to compile this code myself, so there might be minor compiler errors, but the gist should be clear enough.